# How to tweet using Twitter api

Tags: ios5, mgtwitterengine

I have issue regarding using twitter api.How can i use twitter apps in my application?? Because i am already used [this](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/twitter-api-iphone/) and [that](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/). Using those link i can authenticate my twitter apps and get token access but can not post tweet. It gives message like **OAuthTwitterDemo[26757:bf03] Request B4EA76F7-18A2-41EB-940B-7DD138E9389D failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"**

I am using MGTwitterEngine SDK. So tell me solution for my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in priority in apps. When you create apps on twitter then you give permission like Read-Write than this error will not come.